# how to make bootstrap 5 carousel with intro line and button responsive on all devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am making a website using Bootstrap 5. In the header of the website, I am using a carousel from Bootstrap as my header. The carousel image allows for text and a button to be displayed as well. I want the image, text, and button to be responsive. I tried using media queries but I am new to CSS I am not sure how to do it. Right now when I open my website on my phone I can't see the button that is supposed to be in the header.

### This is what it looks like on my computer [image]

### This is what it looks like on my phone [image]

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | Project___ Name_____</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="../assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="../assets/cctv.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        </div> 
      
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
c-item {
    height: 90%;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```css
c-item {
    height: 90%;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | Project___ Name_____</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="../assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="../assets/cctv.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/datacenter-002 - Copy.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/digital-signage-005.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/general-support-001.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/net-support.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/pos.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="./assets/telecom.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project___ Name_____">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" class="stretched-link"></a>

            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        </div> 
      
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```